# What is a word to describe a graduate with the highest graduation score?

Tags: word-request

If you happen to come on top of all your university colleagues in terms of your overall grades, what would you be called? Is there a word for "the first among his class" especially a class that has graduated from university?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a specific word, but idiomatically, we often say "he was first in his class."

It's also usually (although not always) true that the first-in-class receives the title of [valedictorian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valedictorian).

Answer (score -1):

In the U.S. and Canada, at least, the highest ranked graduate was traditionally granted the honor of giving the valediction (i.e. farewell address) at the commencement exercises, and thus the student with the highest grade point (or whatever other mechanism is used to rank the students) became known as the ***[valedictorian](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/valedictorian)***. The second-ranked graduate was given the honor of giving the salutation (i.e. greeting address) at commencement, and thus became known as the *[salutatorian](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/salutatorian)*.

I think nowadays the salutatory address is rare, and the valedictory is not necessarily made or made by the top-ranked student. For one, by educational philosophy, many want to de-emphasize scores as the sole measure of one's scholarship. For another, because of hypercompetitiveness or grade inflation depending on your social outlook, the local high school where I grew up once recorded no fewer than 16 graduates tied for #1. They had received perfect scores in the honors track in all classes. Suffice to say, there was no room in the commencement program for 16 speeches to be given.

Moreover, class rank, while still prominent in secondary education, is not commonly calculated at the university level; diplomas with distinction may be classed as *summa cum laude* (or *with highest honors*), *magna cum laude* (or *with high honors*), and/or *cum laude* ( *with honors*) in some programs at some institutions, but the criteria vary and such distinctions are not made everywhere.

I do not believe either set of terminology has much use in the rest of the Anglophone world. More generically, you may say someone was *ranked first in her class* or that *she was top-ranked*.

Comment: Very elaborate and useful. Thank you. I thought a commencement speech was only a university custom. It's good that high school students as well have graduation ceremonies where they have valediction. In Egypt, our lower education standards don't make it necessary for either schools or colleges to organize graduation ceremonies. So I probably should never translate the Arabic word for top-ranked student as valedictorian.